# Why cant i use Bootstrap Code in VS Code/React?

Tags: css, react-bootstrap

Hi im trying to use this code in my VS Studio project and i cant figure out how to display it. I know it is a Bootstrap Code which is basically a CSS Code. So can i just save this code as a Card.css class? And how do i display it then in my Code?
Especially as i want to make it responsive (change border colour on click to mark as selected).

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div> 
}
```

Im new to front end and im doing a an udemy course to learn more but would still aprecciate an explanation.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

You should use `className` in react instead of `class` you can check it here https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html
and also if you want to use inline style it would look like this `stye={{width: '18rem'}}`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use bootstrap for styling components,  you need to import bootstrap module into your project.

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    ...
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-body-classname": "^1.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    }
}
```

Then you can use bootstrap class names in your component.
TestComponent.js

```
function TestComponent(props){
    return (
        <div className="row">
           <div className="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
               <a
                className="btn btn-primary"
                href="https://test.com/dashboard#/signup"
               >
                  Try now
               </a>
           </div>
           <div className="col-lg-9 col-sm-6">
               <a
                className="btn btn-second"
                href="https://test.com/dashboard#/signin"
               >
                  Sign In
               </a>
           </div>
        </div>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In React.js, use `className` instead of `class`. But using Bootstrap.js in React is still not recommended.